# Moderation Strike Update

Tags: discussion

I had previously shared [a post regarding the Stack Exchange Moderation Strike](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1514/stack-exchange-moderation-strike). I wanted this community to know that while the strike hasn't officially been called off, it appears to be winding down. Many moderators have resumed moderating duties and the automated moderation tools that are maintained by the community are being reactivated.

Stack Exchange has released a new set of AI Content Moderation guidelines. As before, I can't reveal the details of the policy. This was at the request of the moderators' community and not a directive of Stack Exchange. However, the new policy has been well received by the moderators' community. In my personal opinion, it's commonsense and largely reflects what the moderators on this site had been doing anyway. If you see something that you suspect is AI generated, please flag it. The mods will handle it.

I can't speak to the other issues that the striking moderators had raised. As mentioned before, [I didn't participate in the strike](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1516/4239) and wasn't involved in any of the discussions.

I've shared this in the spirit of open communication, not because I expect anyone to take any action based on this post. I simply didn't want to leave the community in the dark regarding major developments with the strike. If the strike continues to wind down, as I expect it will, I won't share anything further. If something unexpected happens, I will.

If anyone has any questions, please feel free to ask them. I'll share anything that I'm able to share.